# What is the most efficient way display threaded graphics in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5, qt5.4

This isn't my project, but for simplicity's sake let's say I just need to print moving squares (which is what I actually did as an intermediate step).  I have seen so many ways to make graphics in Qt but it's really unclear to me what is the "best" way.

I want my graphics running in a separate thread of course, and I have made this happen by simply painting to a widget or by moving the painting functionality into its own thread and also by painting to an image in a different thread and then displaying the image.  I do this by making a QObject and then assigning it to a QThread, not by subclassing QThread and reimplementing run().

These ways all slow down after a couple thousand squares moving around the screen.  I thought that this would be the simplest way to display graphics but I know there are other ways using openGL or QGraphicsView.  I'm hoping stack overflow can save me research time and point me in the right direction.

Also, in case I am doing it the right way but implementing it wrong, here is some of my code:

In the render area:

```
RenderArea::RenderArea(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    m_image = new QImage(size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    m_imageThread = new QThread();
    m_imageMaker = new ImageMaker(size());

    m_imageMaker->moveToThread(m_imageThread);

    setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);

    QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);

    //Frame rate approximations: 60FPS ~ 17 ms, 30FPS ~ 33 ms
    timer->start(33);

    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(requestImageUpdate()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(newImageParams(const QSize &)),
        m_imageMaker, SLOT(makeImage(const QSize &)));
    connect(m_imageMaker, SIGNAL(theImage(const QImage &)), this, SLOT(updateImage(const QImage &)));
    connect(m_imageThread, SIGNAL(finished()), m_imageMaker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(doubleEntities()), m_imageMaker, SLOT(doubleEntities()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(halveEntities()), m_imageMaker, SLOT(halveEntities()));

    m_imageThread->start();
}

RenderArea::~RenderArea()
{
    m_imageThread->quit();
    m_imageThread->deleteLater();
}

void RenderArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */)
{
    QPainter widgetPainter(this);
    widgetPainter.drawImage(0,0,*m_image);
}

void RenderArea::updateImage(const QImage& image) {
    *m_image = image;
    m_displayUpdatePending = false;
    update();
}

void RenderArea::requestImageUpdate() {
    if(!m_displayUpdatePending) {
        m_displayUpdatePending = true;
        emit newImageParams(size());
    }
}

void RenderArea::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    switch (event->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_Plus:
        emit doubleEntities();
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Minus:
        emit halveEntities();
        break;
    default:
        QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
    }
}
```

In the image maker:

```
ImageMaker::ImageMaker(QSize parentSize, QObject* parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_numEntities = 128;
    m_upperBound = 0;
    m_rightBound = parentSize.width();
    m_lowerBound = parentSize.height();
    m_leftBound = 0;

    //seed the random number generator
    QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
    qsrand((uint)time.msec());

    m_mutex.lock();
    randomizeEntities();
    m_mutex.unlock();
}

ImageMaker::~ImageMaker()
{

}

void ImageMaker::makeImage(const QSize & parentSize) {
    m_mutex.lock();

    advanceEntities();

    m_rightBound = parentSize.width();
    m_lowerBound = parentSize.height();

    QImage image(parentSize, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);


    QPainter imagePainter(&image);
    imagePainter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

    imagePainter.setPen(QColor(0,0,0));

    for (int i = 0; i < m_numEntities; ++i) {
    imagePainter.drawRect(m_entityList.at(i).at(0),m_entityList.at(i).at(1),10,10);
    }

    imagePainter.setPen(QColor(255,0,0));
    imagePainter.drawText(10,10,QString::number(m_numEntities));

    imagePainter.end();

    m_mutex.unlock();

    emit theImage(image);
}

void ImageMaker::randomizeEntities() {
    m_entityList.clear();

    for(int i = 0; i < m_numEntities; ++i) {
        QList<int> thisRow;
        thisRow.push_back(qrand() % (m_rightBound + 1)); //random starting X coordinate
        thisRow.push_back(qrand() % (m_lowerBound + 1)); //random starting Y coordinate

        int tempRandX = (qrand() % 4) + 1;
        int tempRandY = (qrand() % 4) + 1;
        tempRandX *= (qrand() % 2) ? -1 : 1;
        tempRandY *= (qrand() % 2) ? -1 : 1;

        thisRow.push_back(tempRandX);                  //random starting X velocity
        thisRow.push_back(tempRandY);                  //random starting Y velocity

        m_entityList.push_back(thisRow);
    }
}

void ImageMaker::advanceEntities() {
    for (int i = 0; i < m_numEntities; ++i) {
        QList<int> thisRow = m_entityList.at(i);
        int xPos = thisRow.at(0);
        int yPos = thisRow.at(1);
        int xVel = thisRow.at(2);
        int yVel = thisRow.at(3);

        xPos += xVel;
        yPos += yVel;

        if ((xPos < 0 && xVel < 0) || (xPos > m_rightBound && xVel > 0)) xVel *= -1;
        if ((yPos < 0 && yVel < 0) || (yPos > m_lowerBound && yVel > 0)) yVel *= -1;

        thisRow.clear();
        thisRow << xPos << yPos << xVel << yVel;

        m_entityList.replace(i, thisRow);
    }
}

void ImageMaker::halveEntities() {
    m_mutex.lock();
    if (m_numEntities > 16) {
        m_numEntities /= 2;
    }
    randomizeEntities();
    m_mutex.unlock();
}

void ImageMaker::doubleEntities() {
    m_mutex.lock();
    m_numEntities *= 2;
    randomizeEntities();
    m_mutex.unlock();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to optimize your rendering speed by tackling multithreading optimizations you are doing it wrong.

What you should try to do is to batch the rendered primitives in only one draw call if possible (so, instead of drawing 1000 times 1 square, you should try drawing 1000 squares in one go).

I advise you to point your research in the OpenGl rendering optimizations direction (and learn how QT batches objects).

Comment: How exactly would I draw 1000 squares with one draw?  I can declare the square outside the loop and draw it over and over inside the loop translating between each step but that doesn't speed things up.  Also this will be more complicated in the long run and having the graphics running in a separate thread is a requirement to keep the UI active doing other things.  I had a suspicion that OpenGL might provide the best solution but a higher up is resisting that path and won't even approve me exploring it but I might just do it anyway...

Comment: You can create 1000 squares in the same vertex buffer,with vertices positions already moved in world space, and then have a index buffer to go with that references the vertices in the correct order to make the squares (it should be something like 0,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9....). Then you have just 1 draw call. This approach works if your squares are static geometry. If you have dynamic objects that move in 2d you could take into consideration giving the 2d position as a varying instead of an uniform, the rotation as a single float (if needed) and the scale as another float (if needed).

Comment: Furthermore, if your 2d coordinates are in screen space (like most likely they are) you could have both x and y information given in a single integer composed of 2 shorts, then use bit masking and shifting to get back the information in the vertex shader. This will allow you to recreate the world matrix inside the VS , then you send the camera and perspective matrix product as a uniform.

Answer (score 0):

You could use QGraphicsScene and 1000 QGraphicsRectItem. 
This is the most portable and efficient way to do this (QGraphicsScene is quite optimized).

The most efficient way may be using OpenGL, but I am not sure it would worth the effort.